# Why does the input parameter value change into the return value before the forward function runs when the return value's name is same?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, pre-trained-model

```
def forward(self, z, temp=None, rescale_logits=False, return_logits=False):
        assert temp is None or temp==1.0, "Only for interface compatible with Gumbel"
        assert rescale_logits==False, "Only for interface compatible with Gumbel"
        assert return_logits==False, "Only for interface compatible with Gumbel"
        # reshape z -> (batch, height, width, channel) and flatten
        print(z)
        z = rearrange(z, 'b c h w -> b h w c').contiguous()
        
        ......

        return z_q, loss, (perplexity, min_encodings, min_encoding_indices)
```

```
def load_vqgan(config, ckpt_path=None, is_gumbel=False):
  if is_gumbel:
    model = GumbelVQ(**config.model.params)
  else:
    model = VQModel(**config.model.params)
  if ckpt_path is not None:
    sd = torch.load(ckpt_path, map_location="cpu")["state_dict"]
    missing, unexpected = model.load_state_dict(sd, strict=False)
  return model.eval()
```

```
h = model1024.quantize.forward(h) #don't use same name
a = model1024.quantize.forward(h) #works well
```

When the return value's name is the same as the input parameter, `h` will be the return value before the `forward` function runs. e.g. `print(z)` in the `forward` line 6 will print the return value.When I change `a` to accept the return value, it works well.

Is this a bug or a feature of pytorch?
(Forgive my poor English writting:)

I expect that the `h` doesn't change before the forward function runs.